# Undefined symbols for x86_64 - iOS - 64-bit transition - Xcode6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-simulator

I apologise for a dumb question. I really had tough time with this.

I am now, converting my existing code to support 64-bit. My app uses few frameworks
(I use [kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework))

And I get this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyFrameworkClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyUI(iPhone_MyVC.o)
```

`MyFrameworkClass` is defined in my framework, Which I built using the below settings

[image: Framework Settings]

In my project, I use this framework and have the same build setting as above.

I am sure, I have the same setting throughout. But still I get this error. Am unsure, what else Am I missing.

Comment: Did you try to change "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the static library for individual architectures and then 'lipo' them together.

Check out the excellent article here: http://blog.diogot.com/blog/2013/09/18/static-libs-with-support-to-ios-5-and-arm64/

Answer (score 1):

You are building your lib for arm only, then you try to run it on x86 (simulator).
Make a lib that supports x86 (64) and use that for debug, the one you have for production.

Answer (score 1):

You should include more of the error message for better help, but it looks as though whatever is providing the MyFrameworkClass class doesn't have a simulator x86_64 slice.

With Xcode 6, you update your project to use Xcode's provided framework target instead of using kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework